# Multiple sites link to one back end, how to track which site traffic came from in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have this web service that I'm trying to offer to multiple businesses of the same genre. They are all individual businesses not affiliated with each other but they can all use one database for submitting info. I basically want to put a link on each separate website that these businesses already have that will point a user to a generic login form that will dump their info into my database and track which company they came from. So if a user goes to Company A and clicks "sign up", i want it to take them to the sign up form but on the back end I'll know to put Company A's credentials with the user affiliation. Likewise if they went to Company B, i'd associate them with Company B. I don't know how to go about doing this in Laravel. Can i generate a custom URL for each company? if so, how do i do that so that i can track the company info? Side note: every company who uses this would also have a company profile with all their info already in my system. Could i create a database column for "company URL" and throw an if statement saying "if url==company A, do 'this'"? I just need a good direction to start in. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a header to the request going to Laravel says which company the request came from

Comment: What should that look like?

Comment: are you using js for requests or just normal views?

Comment: Normal views for now. I'd like to stick with that as much as possible. I'm not incredibly proficient at JavaScript outside of manipulating elements

Comment: so the best way to do it is include the company as a parameter in the url

Comment: So "url.com?company=companyID" then in the view I could put a hidden field with value=$_GET('company'). Is this accurate? Then when I submit the form that value will get submitted?

Comment: that's right, or you just add a hidden field to the form  if it's a POST request with the company id, then retrieve it later in controller

Comment: Yes the form will be a post request after the user fills out all that data. But as far as embedding a link to the different company sites, creating that custom url with the company parameter and grabbing it with the$_GET would work right? That value should get submitted with the form as it goes to the controller to get saved to the database right? If this would work then I'll probably just do that because it's a simple solution. But just for my education, how would I do it as a post like you suggested?

Comment: <form action="/your-link-here" method="post">

Comment: Oh I see, I put a form with method post on the external site with a hidden field assigned to the company ID. Then I change my GET to POST and that would work?

Comment: yes and in the controller that receives the post request, you can access the company_id by `$request->company_id`, more on this: `https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#accessing-the-request`

Answer (score 0):

Company model has many users and User model belongs to company change your routes of Login and Register Controllers to add company on your requests

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many